# didSelectRowAt doesn't affect cellForRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to get different label text when UITabelViewCell is pressed but I can't get it working. The default value of `completed` is false, when touched it should be true and then label should be changed. Inside the didSelectRowAt the `completed` value is different so it's good but I can't pass it to cellForRowAt.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var listItems : [ListItem] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var plusButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    //...
    }


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return listItems.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        var item = listItems[indexPath.row]

        item.completed = !item.completed // changing from true to false and rom false to true
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CellData{
            let item = listItems[indexPath.row]
            cell.nameLabel.text = item.name
            cell.userLabel.text = item.addedBy

            if(item.completed == true){ //didSelectRowAt doesn't affect this item.completed
                cell.doneLabel.text = "done"
            } else {
                cell.doneLabel.text = "not"
            }
            return cell
        } else{
            return CellData()
        }
    }
}
```

ListItem.swift:

```
struct ListItem{
    var name : String!
    var addedBy : String!
    var completed : Bool!

    init(name: String, addedBy: String, completed: Bool){
        self.name = name
        self.addedBy = addedBy
        self.completed = completed
    }

}
```

Comment: In Swift, structs are copied. You are modifying the state of a copy of ListItem, not the ListItem instance within the list itself. After changing the state of the ListItem, you will need to set listIems[indexPath.row] to the new "snapshot".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ListItem is a struct when you update it, it doesn't updated on the list as struct is always copied.
I think you should do something like :

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  var item = listItems[indexPath.row]
  item.completed = !item.completed //
  listItems[indexPath.row] = item
   tableView.reloadData()
 }
```

Comment: or you can use  Mutating Function

Comment: Oh, that actually works! So `listItems[indexPath.row] = item` gets a value of the listItems at the current index and updates only item.completed which was changed? Moreover, maybe it would be easier to implement on the class?